# Extract <Point> coordinates from KML using shell tools

Tags: awk, sed, geolocation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Test.kmz</name>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Test</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>48.7893522149238</longitude>
            <latitude>35.11072013511394</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <heading>-0.1257146222858709</heading>
            <tilt>27.02159138599089</tilt>
            <range>804.546845381412</range>
            <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin160</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
            <coordinates>48.78741496263481,35.11017636516465,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I would like to extract the `48.78741496263481,35.11017636516465` from a KML (but in reverse order) as `35.11017636516465,48.78741496263481`. Is this a task for sed or awk?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using an XML parser for this e.g. `xmlstarlet sel -N kml='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' -t -c '//kml:coordinates/text()' -n yourfile.xml` or `xmlstarlet sel -N kml='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' -t -v 'concat(//kml:latitude,",",//kml:longitude)' -n yourfile.xml` . See for example [Why does this XPath expression not return the correct value in xmlstarlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16306883/4440445)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AWK:

```
awk -F '[>,]' '/coordinates/ {print $3","$2}' file
```

- search for the pattern *coordinates* and prints the 3rd field and 2nd field.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"[<>]" '/longitude/{long=$3}/latitude/{print $3","long}' file.txt
```